# Retrieving elements from an array using events in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, dom-events

I am getting [object, object] instead the elements from the array in the 'categories' function. Though I am not sure, perhaps this is expected and I am just getting it wrong.

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

    Template.ipsosboard.helpers({
         'categories': function() {
        return array; // Some data stored as JS Object in lib.
    },
        'currentElement': function() {
            return Session.get('selectedEvent');
        }
    });

    Template.ipsosboard.events({
        "change #category-select": function(event, template) {
            var selectedEvent = $(event.currentTarget).val();
            Session.set('selectedEvent', selectedEvent);
            console.log("EventNum: " + selectedEvent);
        }
    });

}; //end of client code.

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    //code to run by server here.
};
```

Comment: Have you tried getting the value with vanillajs? ie. `event.currentTarget.value`? This smells like something weird about jquery

Comment: I got it wrong. It was normally returning an object as the file was a JS object containing the data I was trying to get. See the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to fix it. It needed to convert the object into an array. Note: the 'data' is a json file stored as a JS object in lib folder of the project, thus I needed to convert it.

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

    Template.ipsosboard.helpers({
         'categories': function() {
```

> It needed to be converted to array using the function below.

```
        var myObj = data;
        var array = $.map(myObj, function(value, index) {
            return value;
        });
        return array;
    },
```

> So now it returns the data as required.

```
        'currentElement': function() {
            return Session.get('selectedEvent');
        }
    });

    Template.ipsosboard.events({
        "change #category-select": function(event, template) {
            var selectedEvent = $(event.currentTarget).val();
            Session.set('selectedEvent', selectedEvent);
            console.log("EventNum: " + selectedEvent);
        }
    });

}; //end of client code.

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    //code to run by server here.
};
```